# Make video capture to be grayscale and draw rectangle in it using opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I want to draw a rectangle in a video capture that I converted to gray.

This is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if (!cap.isOpened())
    {
        // print error msg
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("gray", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    int pointf[8][4] = { 
                            {100,100 , 150,50},
                            {100,250 , 150,200},
                            {100,430 , 150,380},
                            {295,200 , 345,150},
                            {295,400 , 345,350},
                            {490,100 , 540,50},
                            {490,250 , 540,200},
                            {490,430 , 540,380}
                            };
    int i;
    int j;
    Mat frame;
    Mat gray;
    for (;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;

        cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            rectangle(frame, Point(pointf[i][0],pointf[i][1]), Point(pointf[i][2], pointf[i][3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
        }
        imshow("gray", gray);
        imshow("gray",frame);   
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;

    }

    return 0;

}
```

In the result, I succeed to draw eight of rectangle, but the video is not in a gray scale. If i reorder the imshow (make video gray first, then draw the rectangle), it will make a video in grayscale, but the rectangle didn't show.

So, any suggestion what I suppose to do?
I'm new in using OpenCV.
I use OpenCV 3.1.0 and C++ in Visual Studio 2015
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code closely. Here's what you're doing:

```
    imshow("gray", gray);
    imshow("gray",frame);
```

What this does is that first it displays your greyscale image in a window called grey, and then immediately displays your color image `frame` in the same window. Which means that you don't get to see your gray image at all. That's your **first error**.

Your **second error** is in the statement:

```
rectangle(frame, Point(pointf[i][0],pointf[i][1]), Point(pointf[i][2], pointf[i][3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
```

`frame` is your RGB image, **not your gray image**, so you're not drawing a rectangle on your grey image at all.

If you need to convert your original image to greyscale and then draw a rectangle on it, here's what your do:

```
for (;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;

        cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            //draw rect on gray, not frame
            rectangle(gray, Point(pointf[i][0],pointf[i][1]), Point(pointf[i][2], pointf[i][3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
        }
        //display the Mat objects in different windows
        imshow("gray", gray);
        imshow("original",frame);   
        if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;

    }
```